# Calculate the cohomology group of $U(n)$ by spectral sequence.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology, spectral-sequences

Here $U(n)$ is the unitary group, consisting of all matrix $A \in M_n (\mathbb{C})$ such that $AA^*=I$

**Problem** How to calculate the integer cohomology group $H^*(U(n))$ of $U(n)$? What if $O(n)$ replace $U(n)$?

> My primitive idea is that: as for $U(n)$, it is a Lie group and can
>   acts transitively on the unit sphere with a isotropy group (or say
>   stabilizer) $U(n-1)$. Hence, $U(n)/U(n-1) = S^{2n-1}$ and  we have a
>   fibre bundle  $$ \pi : U(n) \to S^{2n-1}$$ with fibre $U(n-1)$. Then,
>   we try to use spectral sequence and Leray's theorem to calculate.

Although it seems that we should calculate it by induction,  I don't know how to continue. Moreover, someone could use any other method as long as it work.

Comment: Your method seems like the correct one.  Have you tried working through the spectral sequence for some small n?

Answer (score 12):

I'll expand on the hint given by Robert.  $U(1)$ is just $S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}$, and its cohomology ring is the exterior algebra $\Lambda[c_1]$.  Here, the subscript of the generator indicates its degree.

For $n = 2$, we have, as you described, a fibre bundle $U(1) \to U(2) \to S^3$.  Thus there is a Serre spectral sequence with 
\begin{equation}
E_2^{p,q} = H^p(S^3,\mathcal{H}^q U(1)) \cong H^p(S^3) \otimes H^q(U(1)) \Rightarrow H^{p+q}(U(2)).
\end{equation}

We have $E_2^{p,q} \cong \Lambda[c_1,c_3]$.  By lacunary reasons, this spectral sequence collapses on the second page, and so we deduce $H^*(U(2)) \cong \Lambda[c_1,c_3]$.

In general, the spectral sequence for the fiber bundle $U(n-1) \to U(n) \to S^{2n-1}$ always collapses on the second page, and you can use induction to prove the proposition $H^*(U(n)) \cong \Lambda[c_1,c_3,\ldots,c_{2n-1}]$.

I like Mimura and Toda's *The topology of Lie groups* as a reference for these types of calculations.  If I recall, they also discuss how to obtain the above proposition using Morse theory (or maybe just a rational decomposition of $U(n)$).

You also asked about $O(n)$, which is trickier.  First, $O(n)$ is not path-connected, but has two path components each homeomorphic to $SO(n)$, so we may as well consider $SO(n)$ instead.  There is a section in Hatcher (3.D) that is dedicated to computing the mod 2 cohomology of $SO(n)$, using a cell decopmosition.

You can also compute the mod 2 cohomology of $O(n)$ and $SO(n)$ using spectral sequences, but the problem here is that the analogous spectral sequences need not collapse, so the analysis is more subtle.  One can instead induct on *Stiefel manifolds*, which generalize $O(n)$.  I learnt how to do this from [May et al's notes on characteristic classes](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/CHAR/charclasses.pdf).  In particular, see Theorem 2.4 for the cohomology groups of $SO(n)$, although the ring structure requires consideration of Steenrod operations.  May also discusses cohomology away from the prime 2.

Comment: Thank you! I'm a little confused with your notation $Λ[c_1,c_3,…,c_{2n−1}]$? Could you tell me about it ?

Comment: By $\Lambda[c_1,c_3,\ldots,c_{2n-1}]$ I mean the exterior algebra on the generators $c_1, \ldots, c_{2n-1}$.  Think of it as a polynomial algebra, but with  skew-commutativity imposed instead.  Also, we have $c_i \in H^i$, which gives the grading in cohomology. For example, $H^6(U(3))$ is freely generated by the element $c_1 c_5$ (and $c_3^2 = 0$).

Comment: Sorry, would you mind give some details about how to get $H^∗(U(2))$ . After I read Bott's book , I still cannot understand how you get $E^2=\Lambda[c_1,c_3]$

Comment: Right, sorry about the delay!  Anyway, we know that $U(2)$ is a $S^1$-bundle over $S^3$.  The homology of $S^1$ is $\Lambda[c_1]$, and the homology of $S^3$ is $\Lambda[c_3]$.  The $E^2$ page of the Serre spectral sequence is just $H^*(S^3) \otimes H^*(S^1)$ since the base $S^3$ is simply-connected.   So $E^2 = \Lambda[c_3] \otimes \Lambda[c_1] \cong \Lambda[c_1,c_3]$.

Comment: @JHF Would you mind elaborating on why $S^3$ being simply-connected implies that the $E^2$ page is $H^\ast(S^3) \otimes H^\ast(S^1)$?