# Computing the cohomology ring of U(n) with Leray-Hirsch theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The problem is to find the cohomology ring of the unitary group. The idea is to look at the fibration $U(n-1) \to U(n) \to S^{2n-1}$ and use the Leray-Hirsch theorem. But I don't understand why this theorem can be used here. Can you help me?

PS. In this question ([Calculate the cohomology group of $U(n)$ by spectral sequence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306376/calculate-the-cohomology-group-of-un-by-spectral-sequence)) the same problem is solved with Serre spectral sequence but I'm a bit afraid of spectral sequences yet so I prefer a solution using only Leray-Hirsch theorem.

Comment: This is done in Corollary 4D.3 in Hatcher's book (page 434 of the current version).